# Asymptotic notation Big Omega analysis

Tags: complexity-theory

I've tried calculating this function and I am a bit unsure of my result. I set it to True. Can anyone explain if my answer is correct and why?

```
(3 log 2 n + 55 log(n 10 ) + 8 log n) · log n = Ω(log 10 n)
```

I set it to True

Comment: just remove all of the constants, distribute using algebra, and that will tell you your order or magnitude

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct, but can be further simplified to `Ω(log(n))` as `log(10n) + log(10) + log(n)` and `log(10)` is a constant.
To prove that `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` you need to show that `g(n)` is a "lower bound" asymptotically of `f(n)`.
The formal definition is that `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` is there exists some `c, n0 > 0` s.t. for all `n > n0` it holds that `f(n) >= g(n)`.
Recall that for every natural integer bigger than 2 it holds that `log(n) > 1` so
`(3log(2n) + 55log(10n) + 8log n) · log n > 3log(2n) + 55log(10n) + 8log(n) > 8log(n) > log(n)`.
Choose `c = 1, n0 = 2` and we got that for all `n > n0`: `(3log(2n) + 55log(10n) + 8log n) · log n > log(n)`, thus `(3log(2n) + 55log(10n) + 8log n) · log n = Ω(log(n)`.